# Remove percentage printf and shell

Tags: shell, printf, zsh

I'm beginning to learn the shell commands. And I don't know how to remove the percent character in the end.

Example: `printf poo` shows `poo%`

I'm on mac and I use oh my zsh!

Answer (score 4):

The `printf` command doesn't start a new line after the output. The `%` character you see is from `zsh`. It indicates that the preceding line is potentially incomplete (because there was no terminating newline).

To fix this, try `printf 'poo\n'` or `echo poo` (`echo` adds a newline by default).

Answer (score 1):

The percentage sign (`%`) you see at the end is an absence of a trailing newline character, or in other words, an incomplete line.

#### Solution:

You can remove the percentage sign by appending core code with `; echo`.

#### Example:

```
# Issue
$ printf "foo"
poo%

# Solution
$ printf "foo"; echo
foo
```